# ListBox selection issue in Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, listboxitem

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        LIST data = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as LIST;
        string result = data.item.ToString();
    }
```

I am having problem with listbox selection in Windows Phone, I have set selection mode of Listbox to "Multiple",
but problem is that I have listpicker and listbox in my phone application page,
I am selecting first listbox item and selecting list picker item,
now I am not able to select that item of listbox that I have selected previously,
how to solve it?
If I select other item, then I am able to select previously selected item in listbox.
Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide at least some code, that reproduces your problem. Answering this question will result in wild guesses

Comment: @Jaihind I meant to say that, if I select item number 1 in listbox, then how to  deselect that item automatically, because that item is already selected, so I am not able to select that item.

Comment: is there listbox selection change event in your code ???

Comment: @Jaihind yes, there is

Comment: @VirajShah share ListBox selectionchanged event code.

Comment: @VirajShah give a look to my ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this will help you.

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(listBox1.SelectedIndex==-1)
           return;
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        LIST data = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as LIST;
        string result = data.item.ToString();
          listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: thank you brother..you again did it for me..keep it up..god bless